# videogular infitinity calls to load the video in to the src

Tags: angularjs, html5-video, videogular

I'm using Videogular in my application to play the videos, as I load the videos from a remote server as shown below in to the sources of the config for the videogular. videoLoc is the 'http' location of the mp4 file. I've noticed that in my IIS logs sometimes videogular is repeatedly calling the server to load the video, however I'm unable to replicate this issue I strongly believe it is because of videogular and I see this a lot happening in my production environment which is killing my IIS. Anyone ever faced this issue, how to solve this

sources: [{ src: videoLoc, type: 'video/mp4' }]

Answer (score 0):

You need to trust your resources with [$sce](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce) service which is part of [Angular Sanitize](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize) module.

```
{
    src: $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("http://static.videogular.com/assets/videos/videogular.mp4"),
    type: "video/mp4"
}
```

You have also a some samples on [videogular's demo code](https://github.com/2fdevs/videogular/tree/master/app/scripts/controllers).

Comment: Hi elecash, I already have that in my code as var videoLoc = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl($scope.productinfo.loc + $scope.productinfo.videolist[i].sizes[j].formats[0]['targeturl']);

Comment: @AjaySrikanth I understand that you're setting a video file? Videogular is just a wrapper over HTML video tag so you should have the same problem if you just set a video tag with your source file. Maybe is a missconfiguration on your server?